# Equations don't show correctly in list in a markdown file

Tags: list, math, markdown, equations

I am using Byword to edit a markdown file. The equations in a normal paragraph shows correctly , but it shows the code of the equation when it is in a list. My sample markdown file looks  like this:

```
HTML header: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>

###Test
\\({e}^{i\pi }+1=0\\)

In a paragraph equation \\({e}^{i\pi }+1=0\\)  shows correctly.

In a list, equation shows the latex code:

    1. \\({e}^{i\pi }+1=0\\)
```

The markdown file looks like this:[markdown file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/iyfqm8ybuuz3650/Screen%20Shot%202014-04-04%20at%209.47.53%20AM.png)

The preview looks like this:[preview of the markdown file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/du7a50x3a29u7mi/Screen%20Shot%202014-04-04%20at%209.49.46%20AM.png)

It can be seen that the same equation can't show correctly when it is located in a list.
I googled first, but no relevant information. Is there anyway to solve this problem?

Regards

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your post for future readers).

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have indented the "list" with four spaces, making it a block of preformatted text instead.

Try this:

```
In a list, equation shows the latex code:

1. \\({e}^{i\pi }+1=0\\)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That works like magic~~. The four spaces makes that line highlighted. So If I do want my code to be highlighted that way, is there anything I can do?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Four spaces makes it a ["code block"](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#precode). You can read more about Markdown syntax [here](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) and [here](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet).

Comment: If it is a code block, then every word in the code block should be the same as what I typed. That makes sense. Thanks a lot for you help.